# Сервіса чи Сервісу?

Tags: відмінювання, родовий-відмінок

Доброго дня! Виникло питання як правильніше відмінювати сервіс, коли говоримо із власною назвою:

- переваги/можливості/недоліки сервіс**у** "Вуса, лапи, хвіст"
- переваги/можливості/недоліки сервіс**а** "Вуса, лапи, хвіст"

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian.SE! Це запитання в нас вже було. Я позначив декілька з наявних запитань. Будь ласка, перегляньте відповіді на них. Якщо проблему не вирішено, відредагуйте своє запитання, щоб пояснити, чим воно відрізняється від тих, що є. І дякуємо, що приєдналися до спільноти!

Comment: [«Словники України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) і [«Словник української мови» в 11 томах](http://sum.in.ua/s/servis) кажуть, що _сервіс**у**_.

Comment: P.S.: По-моєму, питання закрите **абсолютно** несправедливо, адже в запитаннях, для яких це запитання начебто є дублікатом, **немає** відповіді на конкретно це запитанням (там є відповіді на _схожі_ запитання для _інших_ слів, а також наведені правила, які вкрай важко тлумачити).

Comment: @Sasha, можливо і так. Але запитання настільки неякісно виписане, що цифри говорять самі за себе: за 17 місяців запитання отримало лише 52 (!) перегляди, включаючи ваш і мій. Тому — згоден з думкою, що «дублікат» — це комплімент цьому запитанню і перебільшення.

Comment: @bytebuster, це нормальна кількість переглядів для запитань того періоду (окремі запитання отримали сотні чи навіть тисячі переглядів, але багато запитань, зокрема дуже якісно й ретельно описаних, мають десятки переглядів). Запитання не дуже добре в тому плані, що не містить власної спроби вирішення; але закривши його через, на мою думку, неправильну причину, ми цілком могли знеохотити автора покращувати його. На мою думку, відповідь на таке запитання лише б збагатила сайт.

Comment: @Sasha, «нормальна кількість для того періоду» — у березні-квітні 2018 був найбільший сплеск активності за всю історію цього сайту. Ділити на невелику кількість дописів. Автор has been warmly welcomed, причин для знеохочення особисто я не знаходжу. З іншого боку, нікому не забороняється відредагувати і відновити це запитання. Тим більше, маючи модераторські повноваження. :)

Comment: @bytebuster, подивіться сусідні запитання.