# Томосу чи томоса?

Tags: відмінювання, родовий-відмінок

Як правильно вживати в родовому відмінку? *Томосу* про автокефалію чи *томоса*? У мережі зустрічаються як [перший](https://www.radiosvoboda.org/a/news/29694084.html), так і [другий](https://dzerkalo.media/vidbulosya-pidpysannya-tomosa-pro-avtokefaliyu-pravoslavnoyi-tserkvy-v-ukrayini/) варіанти.

І чи має *томос* писатися з великої літери?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Як правильно - "елемента" чи "елементу"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/2851/%d0%af%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83)

Comment: Також: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/427/

Comment: Також: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1350/

Comment: Також: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3900/

Comment: Ще окремо від цього: запитання стосовно великої літери має бути оформлене окремо.

Comment: Маьемо велику лажу з елаѕькими закінченьами — приходили через посередників, а самі ьих не унормували. Ось одна з [фем розгльаду](https://maksymus.wordpress.com/2009/04/15/186223/).

Comment: @bytebuster, не думаю (ані що це дублікат, ані що про велику/малу літеру слід писати окремо).

Comment: @Sasha, мені здається очевидним, що це два запитання: одне про [tag:відмінювання] (морфологія), друге про [tag:велика-мала-літера] (граматика). У нас навіть теґи відповідні є. І перша половина — повний дублікат запитання *«про утворення родовому відмінку для іменників II відміни»*. Якщо це не так, то я прямо зараз напишу 100500 подібних запитань про родовий відмінок різних іменників II відміни — по одному слову на запитання.

Comment: @bytebuster, «перша половина — повний дублікат запитання „про утворення родовому відмінку для іменників II відміни“» — якого саме? У будь-якому разі, я найімовірніше незгоден: якщо Ви маєте на увазі запитання про інше слово, то то запитання про інше слово, а якщо в нас є загальне запитання про правила, то то загальне запитання про правила. Теги, ІМХО, тут ні до чого: теги підлаштовують під запитання, а не запитання під теги. Я не бачу причин штучно розривати одне запитання на 2 — але якщо Ви впевнені, спробуйте, будь ласка, спитати на загальній меті, чи обов'язково 2 аспекти 1 слова разривати.

Comment: @Sasha, (1) вашу думку прийнято:«якщо запитання стосується іншого слова, воно не дублікат». Пішов за словником слів II відміни (**це не жарт**, найближчим часом напишу кілька подібних запитань). (2) Ви не бачите причин «штучно» розривати одне запитання на 2 — а оце вам нічого не нагадує? *„Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. **Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once**.“*

Answer (score 1):

[«Вільний тлумачний словник»](http://sum.in.ua/f/tomos) пропонує писати «томосу» (з малої й через *-у*):

> то́мос, -у, чол., церк.
>   Грамота, послання патріархів християнської церкви.
>
> > Попри загальне засудження Діоскора, єгипетські єпископи відмовилися підписати послання (томос) папи Лева, пояснюючи це небезпекою їх убивства після повернення на батьківщину   (Омельчук, Ліснича, Релігійна політика стародавніх і середньовічних держав, 2011);
> >
> > 1933 р. заснований екзархат Московської Патріархії у Північній та Південній Америці, який проіснував до 1970 р., коли Патріарх Московський і всієї Руси Алексій І (Симанський) надав їй Томос про автокефалію від 10 квітня 1970 р. із затвердженням назви «Свята Автокефальна Православна Церква в Америці»    (Пам'ятки, Т. 2: Епістолярна спадщина Івана Огієнка, 2001);
> >
> > Інший засуд неканонічности цього акту [передачі Київської митрополії з-під влади Царгородського патріарха] був зроблений Царгородською патріярхією уже в нашому столітті, в патріяршому томосі з 13 листопада 1924 р. про надання автокефалії Православній Церкві у Польщі, більшість вірних якої становили українці і білоруси (Сучасність, 1989, № 3).
>
> Етимологія:
>   грецьке τόμος — том, шматок; від кореня τεμ- — різати.

Але «Вільний тлумачний словник» не є якимось академічним джерелом, це суто власні спроби колективу сайту sum.in.ua заповнити «прогалини» в «Словнику української мови» 1970-х років.

У книжках вживається і [через *-а*](//www.google.com/search?lr=lang_uk&tbm=bks&q=%22%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%22), і [через *-у*](//www.google.com/search?lr=lang_uk&tbm=bks&q=%22%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%22). Щоправда через *-у* приблизно в 2.5 рази частіше (я налічив 23 трапляння через *-а* і 57 через *-у*, але це приблизно), тож я схиляюся в цьому разі вірити «Вільному тлумачному словнику».

Щодо малої і великої літери, то теж уживають і так, і так (і навіть у лапках). Але річ у тім, що загальні назви (які можна писати з малої) не заборонено написати з великої в певних випадках, наприклад, у релігійних контекстах ([§ 38.18.примітка2 у «Правописі»](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par38p18prym2)), для підкреслення урочистості ([§ 38.3.примітка3 у «Правописі»](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par38p3prym3)) тощо. Тому, враховуючи, що його пишуть і так, і так, я схиляюся до того, що це все-таки загальна назва і його можна писати з малої. Але я непевен. І якщо Ви напишете з великої, то Ви, мабуть, точно не помилитеся (це просто сприймуть, як висловлення поваги).

Comment: Коли всье таки дали відповідь, було б добре також порівньати з иншими елаѕькими словами з кінецьем на _~ос_.

Comment: @stegetsj, чесно кажучи, не знаю таких слів (хіба що _термос_ на думку спадає) і замало часу, щоб шукати. Якщо Ви знаєте або маєте бажання — буду радий доповненню.

Comment: Яку роль виконує у відповіді ця розлога цитата, окрім першого і останнього абзаців?

Comment: @bytebuster, вся цитата — це стаття з «Вільного тлумачного словника». Внутрішні цитати (цитати в цитаті) були наведені всередині відповідної статті «Вільного тлумачного словника», це те, чим укладачі того словника аргументують своє бачення. Можливо, внутрішні цитати краще оформити інакше, наприклад, курсивом, відступом абощо.

Comment: Перепрошую, яким саме чином цитати пояснюють «бачення» автора стосовно `-у` (а не `-а`)? На мою думку, **тлумачний** словник пояснює (раптово) **тлумачення** слова, і саме для цього, вочевидь, ці цитаті наведені автором. Вони аж ніяк не аргументують відмінювання. Ба більше: у жодній з них нема цього слова у родовому відмінку. Я вважаю, що ці цитати заслуговують заміни на `[…]`. Я поставлю мінус поки що.

Comment: @bytebuster, там є приклади малої і великої літери. Ок.